# Need to convert below stored procedure from Oracle to SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle12c

I need to convert below stored procedure from Oracle to SQL, I try to convert it through SqlSever Migration Assistant but that was not able to convert dynamic query. I also need to know how can we alter sequence and get nextval:

```
create or replace 
procedure dep_reset_seq( p_seq_name in varchar2,p_Start_value integer )
is
    l_val number;
begin
    execute immediate
    'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;

    execute immediate
    'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by -' || l_val || 
                                                          ' minvalue ' || p_Start_value;

    execute immediate
    'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;

    execute immediate
    'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by 1 minvalue  ' || p_Start_value;
end;
```

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server (M$ SQL Server, because Oracle is also a SQL Server) has no sequence concept. It uses AutoIdentity fields instead.

Comment: And what does this have to do with C#? Anyway SO is not a code-translation-service. Share what yove tried already and where you´re stuck.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor - from SQL Server 2012 onwards, Sequences are supported.

Comment: @andrew: Thanks, was not aware of that, found it is since 2012 :-( long time to miss it ..

Comment: What I would like to know: Why is the sequence used in that way? get nextval, and recreate sequence with a new startvalue?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server from 2012 onwards supports sequences, there is an alter sequence command : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
The format of the command for altering a sequence is very similar to Oracle.

Getting the next value is a different format of command, accessed using the `NEXT VALUE` construct.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Each of these concepts are pretty easy to search for, with pretty comprehensive documentation existing - so is there a more specific problem you are having?